# How to block "make" command in makefile

Tags: makefile

I write makefile, which structure like following

```
#... Configure basic flags for compiler

.PHONY: mk_mingw
mk_mingw:
# build with mingw(windows)

.PHONY: mk_gcc_linux
mk_gcc_linux:
# build in gcc(linux)

#... some auxiliary unit such as clear, test ...
```

Use the following command when building with mingw(windows)

```sh
#command 1
$ make mk_mingw
```

Use the following command when building with gcc(Linux)

```sh
#command 2
$ make mk_gcc_linux
```

I hope the above two commands are legal in my project.

mk_gcc_linux and mk_mingw are environment of compiler(I specified)

But following commands isn't:

```sh
#command 3
$ make
```

Because it's not specify environment of compiler after **make** command.

I want make to report an error and stop when this situation(command 3) happens.

How do I do in my makefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `make` tries to build the very first target. So you can simply put this on top of your Makefile:

```
.PHONY: first
first:
    @echo Environment not specified!
    @false
# the rest of file is following...
```

But for me it doesn't look quite right. Probably, setting a variable, instead of a dedicated target, is better.

Comment: I think this is just fine, and in fact I have seen this very approach exercised.  I take the target-based selection to be more in the `make` idiom than a variable-based selection, but I guess it depends somewhat on what you actually do in each case.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Well, you're right that depends. But, chances are, one also needs to adjust some other variables depending on the target platform. And it's not very convenient to do that from inside the target's recipe. So one ends up either parsing `MAKECMDGOALS` or going into recursive make. For me variables look more flexible.